# SQL query number being returned incorrectly

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm stumped why this is not returning the correct value.  I have this query:

```
SELECT 
  ClosingMonth,
  CAST(SUM(EstSale10)as DECIMAL (10,2)) as 'EstSale10',
  CAST(SUM(EstSale25)as DECIMAL(10,2)) as 'EstSale25'
FROM(
  SELECT ClosingMonth,
    SUM(EstSaleLessWar) OVER (PARTITION BY ClosingMonth) AS 'EstSale10',
    0.00 AS 'EstSale25'
  FROM dbo.Contracting_SAF
    WHERE OwnerID = '65'
        AND Year = '2013'
        AND ClosingMonth = 'December'
        AND Status != '10'
        AND ConfLevel = 'Not Likely (10%)'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ClosingMonth,
     0.00 AS 'EstSale10',
     SUM(EstSaleLessWar) OVER (PARTITION BY ClosingMonth) AS 'EstSale25'
   FROM dbo.Contracting_SAF
     WHERE OwnerID = '65'
        AND Year = '2013'
        AND ClosingMonth = 'December'
        AND Status != '10'
        AND ConfLevel = 'Low (25%)') T
GROUP BY T.ClosingMonth
```

And my result is the following:

```
December | 0.00 | 29106570.00
```

Problem is using a number_format in PHP shows this value is 29,106,570.00 when it should be only 2,910,657.00 as I get in this single query below:

```
SELECT SUM(EstSaleLessWar) 
FROM Contracting_SAF
WHERE OwnerID = '65' 
    AND Year = '2013' 
    AND ClosingMonth = 'December' 
   AND ConfLevel = 'Low (25%)'
```

result for query:

```
2910657.00
```

Help!!  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the result wrong in SQL Server or does it get corrupted going to PHP, e.g. because it gets converted to a less precise data type?

Comment: Its wrong in SQL as you see in the first set of results - its adding a zero behind the 7 before the decimal.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that. Try removing the first set of `SUM`s and the `GROUP BY T.ClosingMonth` and just displaying the inner `SUM`s to see if that helps you identify the problem.

Comment: Doing so cleans up the issue with the number; however, I'm now getting multiple lines.  Looks to be a line per matching record.  Adding Distinct to the Select takes care of that - just not sure if I'm going to run into problems doing so.

Comment: After further testing my fear is correct.  Distinct does cause issues and leaves out some records

Comment: It seems like you need to figure out why `SELECT * FROM dbo.Contracting_SAF WHERE OwnerID = '65' AND Year = '2013' AND ClosingMonth = 'December' AND Status != '10'  AND ConfLevel = 'Low (25%)'` is processing rows you don't expect.